# HAproxy 1.6 with Lua and TCP redirect

Tags: tcp, lua, haproxy

Hy,
I am trying to redirect traffic using HAproxy based on TCP content.

With Lua, I can register a service that checks the content, like this:

```
core.register_service("chooseserver", "tcp", function(AppletTCP)
  function string.checkit(str)
      --mylogichere
      return string.char('server1')
  end

  tcp_line = AppletTCP:getline()
  server = tcp_line:checkit()
  if server == 'server1'   then
    -- HERE
    AppletTCP:send(tcp_line)
  else
    AppletTCP:send(tcp_line)
  end
end)
```

In HAproxy configuration you can add

```
listen proxy
   bind 127.0.0.1:10001
   tcp-request content use-service lua.chooseserver
```

That will execute the service (and I can log information) but the AppletTCP:send is not working as I expected (no errors) sending the Package to the backend definition and I cannot send the TCP package to a server of my choice.

Not sure if I should use register_action instead for this task, but I was not able to make it work either

I need Lua, because I need to read the content of the TCP package and based in its content send it to another server. I need to be able to split decode and encode strings, iterate arrays, and similar basics operators. If you know any other way would be nice to know too.

Comment: In what way isn't it working the way you expect? Is it throwing an error? Is it just not sending (silently)? Is it crashing? Be specific. Include error and log messages.

Comment: I expected a similar behavior than the applet.send of HTTP Applet class, at least answering the client, but I cannot see anything in the client, and anyway is not my desired output. So, yes, "silently" maybe is the best definition.

Comment: try replace `return string.char('server1')` to `return 'server1'`

Comment: `use-service` is for when the Lua script is the final destination.  Analyzing the content would be done with an action, `tcp-request content lua.xxxx` but you can't "return" a back-end.  You'll need to set HAProxy transaction variables from Lua and select the back end based on that.  What's the back-end logic?  Is Lua strictly necessary?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I tried to use tcp-request content lua.xxx but answer: 
`'tcp-request content' expects 'accept', 'reject', 'track-sc0' ... 'track-sc2', 'sc-inc-gpc0(*)', 'sc-set-gpt0(*)', 'silent-drop', 'use-service', 'set-var(*)', 'lua.chooseserver' in proxy 'proxy' (got 'lua.chooseserver').`
Not sure if I need Lua, will clarify in the question the requirements. But I think so.
Back-end logic is simple, are few (less than 30) destinations.
If I can set variables from "Lua output" based in TCP content, I think I can set the backend with if conditions in HAproxy. Can you point me how to do it?